# Java: Array of Buttons - get the source

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton, actionlistener

Suppose I have an array of buttons

```
private JButton[] myButtons = new JButton[5];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    myButtons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
    myButtons[i].setSize(50, 50);
    panel.add(myButtons[i]);
}
```

How can I add a listener to these buttons so that when I click on one of them, I know at which array position index it is at?

Answer (score 2):

You kind of don't care, start by adding an `ActionListener` to the buttons

```
myButtons[i].addActionListener(this); // Or some other ActionListener
```

In the `actionPeformed` method, you can look up which button it is using the `ActionEvent#getSource`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    for (JButton btn : myButtons) {
        if (btn.equals(evt.getSource()) {
            // Do what ever you need
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton`

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    myButtons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
    myButtons[i].setActionCommand("button " + i);
    myButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(myButtons[i]);
}
```

And when `actionPeformed` is called, use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` to figure out which button was pressed.

A better idea might be to create a dedicated `ActionListener` for each button...

```
public class ButtonActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    private final JButton button;
    public ButtonActionHandler(JButton button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Do what ever you need to do with the button...
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    myButtons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
    myButtons[i].addActionListener(new ButtonActionHandler(myButtons[i]));
    panel.add(myButtons[i]);
}
```

Another idea would be to make use of the `Action` API which would allow you to define a self contained entity which was capable of configuring the button and handling the associated action event by itself.  See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

But which you might use will come down to why you need to identify the buttons in the first place.

Comment: can you explain "myButtons[i].addActionListener(this);" better cuz personally it makes confuse. how this is gonna recongize the right thing?

Comment: plus one you bc of the last idea which is awesome

Comment: @KickButtowski You would either use `ActionEvent#getSource` and compare it to the `buttons` array or use the `actionCommand` (preferably) property of the button and `ActionEvent`

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener in loop, like below if you implement `ActionListener` interface with class. For example,

```
class TestGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
 public TestGUI(){
  for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){
  ....
  myButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
 }
}
```

or, if you have separate Listener class or method.

```
myButtons[i].addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

Than at actionPerformed method you can check with button is clicked,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   if("0".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
     System.out.println("First button is clicked");
   }
   ... so on
}
```

Comment: And getting the array index of the button that was clicked?

Comment: I am sure that part is easy to figure it out do not you agree?

Comment: @Eclipse22, getActionCommand will give you the text of Button. In your case it will be "0", "1"..